# Flutter app is not showing as an icon on the android emulator homescreen

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am trying to build an app. I am using flutter as the framework and VS Code as my IDE. I also have an android emulator installed via android studio. I am trying to implement authentication. If i run my app it opens in the emulator and works just fine. Now i want to test if a user stays logged in when the app is closed (not running in the background) and reopened. However if i close the app in the android emulator, the whole process stops and there is no icon of my app on the home screen with which i could restart it. I have to "run and debug" again in VS Code to restart the process. Is there any way to start the app again via the emulator phone?

I updated the emulator and the flutter package, i changed emulator devices. Did not solve the problem.

Comment: Because when your app id disconnected from debug - you can use hot restart its consider as app is kill and open again - here having a problem with flutter  if you disconnect from debug your all assets will be remove from entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Because when your app is disconnected from debug - you can use hot restart its consider as app is kill and open again - here having a problem with flutter  if you disconnect from debug your all assets will be remove from entire app. Another option - if you want to test your app then make release app and installed in physical device

Comment: is it possible to connect the app to debug?

Comment: @vreithinger brother you want to kill app and again open?

Comment: Just press hot restart on panel your app is kill and open again

Comment: i dont want to hot reload my app. i want to know why the app is not visible on the home screen as an icon

Comment: @vreithinger are you set any assets in app icon? Or its default?

Comment: i did not set any icon assets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250988/discussion-between-rahulvflutterandroid-and-vreithinger).

Comment: strenge @vreithinger

Comment: If you install the app in a physical device ...still you get the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run your app from VS Code itself.

**Use this bottom Menu button to launch emulator:**

[image]

**Select your Emulator from listed / Create a new one:**
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am doing that. The emulator starts and the app starts as well. However if i close the app in the emulator i cannot reopen it as there is no app icon to press.

Comment: have you checked the app in the app drawer?

Comment: yes i have it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you could try adding this to your AndroidManifestXML file

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
```